# What language can be created from a regular expression with nulls?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

The usual regular expressions I have seen are those with non-null inputs (e.g. $a$, $b$). A few days ago, I saw, for the first time, a regular expression that has a null ($∅$) in it.

$$ r_{1}= (cε + d∅)^{*}, Σ = \{c,d\} $$

This confused me since I do not know how a language would be created from $r_{1}$.

What would a language created from a regular expression be like if that regular expression has a null (like $r_{1}$ above)?

Additionally, what would a language be like if the regular expression from which the language is created from contains $ε$ (for example, like $r_{2}=(aε)(bε)ε, Σ = \{a, b\}$, and again, like $r_{1}$ above)?

Comment: [The formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) of a regular expression requires a finite alphabet over which it is defined. What is the alphabet? Also, the empty string is usually denoted by $\epsilon$ or $\lambda$, not by $\emptyset$. It is not clear what $c$ and $d$ mean. Could you edit your post?

Comment: @fade2black $\emptyset$ isn't being used to denote the empty string. $c$ and $d$ are, presumably, characters in the alphabet but it wouldn't make much difference if they were regular expressions, too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I say the same thing, $\emptyset$ does not denote the empty string. $r_{1}= (cε + d∅)^* $ is not a regular expression, is it? We don't have to guess what the asker asks, the question should be clear and unambiguous.

Comment: @fade2black No guessing is required. The question is completely clear (apart from the last paragraph) and I've written a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It should be written either in the set theoretic terms, in which case the $\emptyset$ is acceptable, or it should be written in terms of [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition). But by no means mixing, no matter the question is clear or not.

Comment: @fade2black, I edited the question to include the alphabet. Sorry. I forgot to include the alphabet in the first place.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I edited the last paragraph to make sure it clearer.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Thanks. I covered that very briefly in the fourth paragraph of my answer. Is that enough or should I try to say a bit more?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, it covers the last paragraph enough. If I get this right, $r_{2}$ from the last paragraph of this question would just be equal to $ab$. Is it correct?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Correct.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Oh okay. Another question. Say we have a regular expression that has $ε$ like $r_{3} = (b)^{*}, Σ=\{b\}$. Would the input string, $εεεbεεεbεεε$, be valid?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I apologize for being annoying with my questions.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais It's valid but it denotes exactly the same string as $bb$. $\epsilon\epsilon b$ (to use a shorter example) is the string you get by writing nothing, then writing nothing again, then writing $b$, and that's just the same as writing $b$.

Comment: @fade2black Many authors include $\emptyset$ as part of the syntax of regular expressions. Otherwise your regular expressions cannot describe all regular languages, since they are unable to describe the empty language. You can think of $\emptyset$ as a zero element, since $\emptyset + r = r + \emptyset = r$ and $\emptyset r = r \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression $\emptyset$ matches nothing at all: not the empty string, not any non-empty string.

Any concatenation with $\emptyset$ also matches nothing: a string would only match $d\emptyset$ if it could be divided into some part that matches $d$ and some part that matches $\emptyset$, but no such part exists.  So $d\emptyset$ is the same thing as $\emptyset$: it matches nothing at all.

An alternation ("or") of something with $\emptyset$ has no effect: $c\epsilon+\emptyset$ means "anything that matches $c\epsilon$ or matches $\emptyset$" and that's just "anything that matches $c\epsilon$."

So $c\epsilon+d\emptyset$ is the same thing as $c\epsilon$ which, in turn, is the same thing as $c$.  The regular expression you quote is equivalent to the simple $c^*$.

---

Conceptually, $\emptyset$ plays a similar role to zero in addition and multiplication. Adding zero to anything doesn't change it, just as alternation of a regular expression with $\emptyset$ doesn't change it. Multiplying anything by zero makes it equal to zero, just as concatenation of any regular expression with $\emptyset$ turns it into $\emptyset$.

$\emptyset$ might seem rather pointless as a regular expression. It's needed because, without it, the empty language (the one with no strings at all in it, i.e., the set $\emptyset$) wouldn't be regular. To see this, it's not hard to prove by induction that every regular expression that doesn't contain the character $\emptyset$ must match at least one string. However, we want the empty language to be regular, because it's accepted by an automaton – in fact, by any automaton with no accepting states.

Comment: Would $\{∅\}$ be in $L(r_{1})$, where $r_{1} = cϵ+∅, Σ=\{c\}$?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais That's a category error. Languages are sets of strings, and $\emptyset$ isn't a string. (So, no it's not in $L(c\epsilon+\emptyset)$, for the same reason that an elephant isn't in $L(c\epsilon+\emptyset)$.)

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais That question makes no sense: $L(r_1)$ is a set of words, so a set-of-sets which is not a word can not belong to that language. Anyway, as explained above $c\epsilon+\emptyset$ is equivalent to $c\epsilon$

Comment: @DavidRicherby I see. I get it more now. Would there be cases where $∅$ is necessary in regular expressions (aside from making sure the empty language is regular)?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais No, it's just for making the empty language regular. Any other regular expression that mentions $\emptyset$ is equivalent to one without it: you can use the rules $R\emptyset\equiv\emptyset$, $R+\emptyset\equiv R$ and $\emptyset^*\equiv\epsilon$ to remove $\emptyset$ from any regular expression that includes it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Oh, I see. Thanks a lot!